# How to get a form to be in the middle of a page?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this form with the class, `col-md-4 col-md-offset-4`, but it's too big. If I change it to this class, `col-md-3 col-md-offset-4`, then it'll work, but it won't be placed exactly in the middle of the page anymore. How can get it centered and the same size?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to see this for better understanding about the Grid Basic of Bootstrap. 
 [Link Here](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_basic.asp).

I think it's not possible to make it center of the page because bootstrap only have 12 Span Grids. see in the link. if you make it like this it will make to the center.

```
<div class="col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-5" style="background-color:lavender;">ColSize2</div>
```

But smaller ofcourse.